# Do signal handlers need to be included in every possible context in a process?

Tags: c, multithreading, operating-system, pthreads, signals

For example:

Say I have a signal handler in main() that handles a timer alarm. I also have worker threads that main creates, which do not have this signal handler because the logic required for the signal is contained in main. I believe this will be a problem, because if one of the worker threads is currently running when the signal is sent, it will catch the signal and not have the required signal handler to handle it. But it seems like overkill to include definitions of every single relevant custom signal handler in every possible context. Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: A "signal handler" is a *function*, so it's unclear how you can have one "in" `main()`.

Comment: When you enter your thread function, use `pthread_sigmask` to mask _off_ the signals that you want your main thread to handle.

Comment: Or, to prevent a [slight/possible] race condition, use `pthread_sigmask` in main to mask off the signals. Then, do `pthread_create`. The sub-threads will _inherit_ this mask. Then, after all threads are created, main can restore its mask that _will_ handle the signals.

Comment: signal handlers are process wide - they're not per thread. In a multi threaded environment, any thread could be the one to handle a signal and run its handler when the signal arrives - though you can control which thread could handle signals by using signal masks (pthread_sigmask())

Comment: What is a context? I don't think C has a thing called contexts.

Answer (score 3):

> Say I have a signal handler in main() that handles a timer alarm.

No, you don't.  A signal handler is a function, and C has no meaningful sense in which one function can be inside another.

> I also have worker threads that main creates, which do not have this signal handler because the logic required for the signal is contained in main.

Signal dispositions, including custom handlers, are process-wide properties.  You cannot have different dispositions for the same signal in different threads of the same process.  Moreover, no, the logic for handling a signal is in its signal handler, if it has one, or in the kernel if it doesn't.  The functions available to a process are also a per-process property, not a per-thread property.

> I believe this will be a problem, because if one of the worker threads is currently running when the signal is sent, it will catch the signal and not have the required signal handler to handle it.

Not necessarily, and no.

Every thread has its own signal mask, which controls which signals may be delivered to it.  A thread inherits its signal mask from its parent thread, and can subsequently modify that mask via the `pthread_sigmask()` function.  This way you can control in which thread your signal handlers run and, at least as importantly, which threads can be interrupted by signals, so it is not necessarily the case that signals will be delivered to your worker threads.

But also no, individual threads do not have separate signal handlers in any case, as I already discussed.  Every thread has all the signal handlers the process has, because they belong to the process, not to individual threads.

> But it seems like overkill to include definitions of every single relevant custom signal handler in every possible context. Am I missing something?

Yes.  I'm not sure exactly which parts you're missing, but see above.

Answer (score 0):

A signal handler is *code*, which is shared by all of your threads because all the threads share the process' memory space. Hence, there's no way it will "not have the signal handler".

Now there *might* be linkage from the signal handler to the code that runs in one particular thread and that's something your program needs to handle through the design of your code and data structures.

Assuming you're interested in posix/linux systems, it is possible to mask signals on a per-thread basis with `pthread_sigmask`. One common solution therefore is to block signals in all threads except those that are expecting to handle them.

Some signals are inherently thread-specific (such as floating point exceptions and segmentation violations). See the `signal(7)` man page for more info.